# handling JSON response in Vuejs from nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js

In my process of learning nodejs and Vue, I am writing an application that displays .md files form the server.

I have the webpage open a default .md file when the webpage is hit. I intend to create webpage/ to display a different page.

The NodeJS backend renders the contents and sends it as JSON. (res.json). The Vue code then processes json response and adds the md content in the appropriate `<div>`

However if I hit any other page other than default page I get JSON displayed on the page.

How do I get VueJS to handle the JSON. Should I be sending res.render('index') everytime?

Thanks for your help!

My NodeJS code

```
exports.index = (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
}

exports.defaultPage = (req, res) => {
  console.log('inside default /');
  var response = {};

  fs.readdir('./', (err, files) => {
    var mdFiles = [];
    files.forEach( file => {
      if (path.extname(file) === '.md') {
        mdFiles.push(file);
      }
    });
    response['files'] = mdFiles;
    fs.readFile(mdFiles[0], 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
      if (!err) {
        html = converter.makeHtml(contents);
        response['html'] = html;
        res.json(JSON.stringify(response));
      } else {
        res.json(err);
     }
   });
 });

}
```

vue js (app.js)

```
// app.js

new Vue({
  el: "#mdEditor",

  data: {
          content: '',
          files: [],
        },
  mounted: function() {
    this.defaultPage();
  },

  methods: {
    defaultPage: function() {
      this.$http.get('/defaultPage')
        .then((result) => {
          data = JSON.parse(result.data);
          this.$set(this, 'content', data.html);
          this.$set(this, 'files', data.files);
          this.files.forEach( (data, index, arr) => {
            arr[index] = data.split('.md')[0];
          });
        }, (err) => {
          console.log('error=', err);
       });
    }
  }
});
```

index.html

```
  <div class="container" id="mdEditor">

    <nav class="vertical-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a v-bind:href="file" v-for="file in files">
{{file}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <article>
      <span style="font-size: 150%" v-html="content"></span>
    </article>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should keep all the api routes under "/api" and use all the other directories to send the html template + vueJS so you can control what is seen by vueJS

Comment: But I want to keep the nodejs part as an API service sending JSON and dont want to send the template. How will I design that then?

Comment: You somehow have to serve the front-end files to the user. You can do that with Nginx when on production.